# Does SSMS Express include SQL Server Express on the installation

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I know that this is an incredibly basic question.

If I install SSMS Express, will that include SQL Server Express 2016 in the bundle of files or do I have to download SQL Server Express separately?

I have to go through an admin for installation approvals.  It helps that I know this beforehand.

Comment: **NO!** SSMS Express is ***ONLY*** the management GUI - it does ***NOT*** contain the actual **database engine**

Comment: Honestly, you don't need to install SSMS Express at all. Full SSMS is available for free now - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt238290.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396